# How to get all rows in GridView using Self Join in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview, self-join

I am using Self Join to retrieve data from SQLSERVER Database and displaying the data in GridView.

Data in DepartmentMst table:

```
DepartmentID      DepartmentName       IsActive DepartmentParentID
3                    Admin Panel       1              0
4                    Human Resource    1              0
5               Information Technology 1              0
6                     Operational      1              0
21                    TestDepartment   1              3
22                       Logistics     1              3
```

From above data you can see that AdminPanel Department has its SubDepartment TestDepartment and Logistics with both DepartmentParentID=3 which belongs to main Department i.e AdminPanel.

Now want to display the Data in grid view which will show the DepartmentName and its SubDepartments.

My Query:

```
SELECT  dpt1.DepartmentID as DepartmentID
         ,dpt1.DepartmentName as DepartmentName
        ,dpt1.DepartmentParentID as ParentDepartmentID
        ,dpt2.DepartmentName as ChildDepartment
        ,dpt1.IsActive
  FROM DepartmentMst dpt1,DepartmentMst dpt2
  where (dpt1.DepartmentID=dpt2.DepartmentParentID) and dpt2.IsActive=1
  order by DepartmentID
```

O/P:

```
DepartmentID    DepartmentName  ParentDepartmentID  ChildDepartment  IsActive
3                   Admin Panel    0                   TestDepartment    1
3                   Admin Panel    0                     Logistics      1
```

**But, I need all the DepartmentName with SubDepartmentName. If any Department has no Parent i.e DepartmentParentID=0, then it must be Shown as MainDepartment else its Parent Department Name**

Eg:

```
DepartmentID    DepartmentName  IsActive    DepartmentParentID  ParentDeptName
3                   Admin Panel     1             0                MainDept
4                 Human Resource    1             0                MainDept
5          Information Technology   1             0                MainDept
6                     Operational   1             0                MainDept
21                 TestDepartment   1             3              AdminPanel
22                  Logistics       1             3              AdminPanel
```

How to get the above out put?
Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
    dpt1.DepartmentID as DepartmentID
    ,dpt1.DepartmentName as DepartmentName
    ,dpt2.DepartmentParentID as ParentDepartmentID
    ,ISNULL(dpt2.DepartmentName, 'MainDept') as ParentDepartment
    ,dpt1.IsActive
FROM DepartmentMst dpt1
    LEFT JOIN DepartmentMst dpt2
        ON (dpt2.DepartmentID = dpt1.DepartmentParentID) and dpt2.IsActive=1
ORDER BY DepartmentID
```

If the join condition has no match then all columns from `dpt2` will come back as `NULL` so you can test for that.

Edit: I tried to fix the columns in your query as they didn't seem correct. `dpt1` is your "current" table and `dpt2` is where the parent will be (if any)

Comment: thanks for replying @CyberDude but in Database their is no NULL value in column DepartmentParentID their is Zero (0) to Identify as MainDept

Comment: Yes, and because no department has `Id = 0` then the join condition will yield no match. In this case any column that you output using the `dpt2` alias will come as `NULL`. To better understand what happens just run this query: `SELECT dpt1.*, dpt2.* FROM DepartmentMst dpt1 LEFT JOIN DepartmentMst dpt2 ON dpt2.DepartmentID = dpt1.DepartmentParentID`

Comment: table is same just i have used selfjoin! if i am not wrong your query shows error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'MainDept' to data type int"

Comment: I moved the NULL check now, it should work. Don't confuse self join and inner join. Both your query and mine are self joins because the table is joined to itself. Your original query is an implicit INNER JOIN and will output each combination of 2 rows and then you only filter those pairs for which the parent-child relation matches. This also means that if something has no parent (parent id = 0) it will never match the condition (because there are no rows with id 0) so they are excluded from your output.

Comment: After modifying your query finally i got the output that i need!

SELECT
    dpt1.DepartmentID as DepartmentID
    ,dpt1.DepartmentName as DepartmentName
    ,dpt2.DepartmentParentID as ParentDepartmentID
    ,ISNULL(dpt2.DepartmentName, 'MainDept') as ParentDepartment
    ,dpt1.IsActive
FROM DepartmentMst dpt1
    LEFT JOIN DepartmentMst dpt2
        ON (dpt2.DepartmentID = dpt1.DepartmentParentID) where dpt1.IsActive=1
ORDER BY DepartmentID

Thanks a lot @CyberDude :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21083/discussion-between-shekhar-shete-and-cyberdude)